# How to make custom Hypothesis strategy to supply custom objects?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-hypothesis

Suppose I have a class `Thing`

```py
class Thing:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        ...
```

And suppose I have a function which acts on a list of things.

```py
def do_stuff(list_of_things):
    ...
```

I would like to write unit tests for `do_stuff` involving different instances of lists of `Thing`.

Is there a way to define a custom Hypothesis strategy which provides examples of `list_of_things` for my unit tests on `do_stuff`?

Comment: This boils down to "How to make a custom Hypothesis strategy for `Thing`?", since you'll supply that to `hypothesis.strategies.lists` to make a `list[Thing]` value.

Comment: @chepner Yes, your description of the problem is excellent.

Comment: We've reached the end of my practical knowledge of Hypothesis :) But see https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#composite-strategies for how you can define a strategy that can use, for example, other strategies to create `x` and `y` values so you can return `Thing(x, y)`.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I will post an answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a complicated composite strategy; this is a perfect case for [the `st.builds()` strategy](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#hypothesis.strategies.builds):

```
from hypothesis import given, strategies as st

@given(
    st.lists(
        st.builds(Thing, x=st.integers(), y=st.integers())
    )
)
def test_do_stuff(ls):
    do_stuff(ls)
```

If `Thing.__init__` has type annotations, you can omit strategies for the required arguments and `st.builds()` will fill them in for you (recursively, if it takes an instance of `Foo`!).  You can also use type annotations in your test, and have Hypothesis infer the strategies entirely:

```
@given(ls=...)  # literal "...", Python's ellipsis object
def test_do_stuff(ls: list[Thing], tmpdir):  # and tmpdir fixture
    do_stuff(ls)

@given(...)  # this will provide _all_ arguments, so no fixtures
def test_do_stuff(ls: list[Thing]):
    do_stuff(ls)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `hypothesis.strategies.composite` object, which you can use as a decorator on a function which returns instances of the class you want to generate test cases on.

Here is a short example where we suppose some class `Person` which has the properties `name` and `age`. The `person_objects` function uses strategies for each of these attributes using behaviour that is built-in to Hypothesis. Note the `@composite` above the function header, and that `person_objects` has a parameter called `draw` that is a function called on some existing strategies.

```py
from hypothesis import strategies as st, composite
from my_module import Person

# Define a strategy for generating random names
names = st.text(min_size=1, max_size=50)

# Define a strategy for generating random ages
ages = st.integers(min_value=0, max_value=150)

# Define a custom strategy for generating random Person objects
@composite
def person_objects(draw):
    name = draw(names)
    age = draw(ages)
    return Person(name, age)

# Use the generated Person objects in the decorated function
@given(person_objects())
def test_person_objects(person):
    assert isinstance(person, Person)
    assert isinstance(person.name, str)
    assert isinstance(person.age, int)
    assert 0 <= person.age <= 150
```